How to do all multiple source. s3 excel and api then transform and combine result Seatunnel
Reference to call s3 : https://seatunnel.apache.org/docs/2.3.3/connector-v2/source/S3File/
Reference to call post: Apache Seatunnel, how to make http post call
Source 1 excel from s3
Source 2 http result from api.
My sources as below. it is working dine
"source": [
    {
        "plugin_name": "S3File",
        "bucket": "s3a://bucket-name",
        "path": "/path/to/excel/file.xlsx",
        "fs.s3a.endpoint": "s3.region.amazonaws.com",
        "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider": "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider",
        "file_format_type": "EXCEL",
        "skip_header_row_number": 1,
        "result_table_name": "user_data_from_excel",
        "sheet": 0,
        "schema": {
            "fields": {
                "user_id": "string",
                "user_name": "string",
                "email": "string",
                "role": "string",
                "status": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "plugin_name": "Http",
        "url": "http://api-endpoint.com/api/users/graphql",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "{\"query\":\"query GetAllUsers($filter: UserFilter) { getAllUsers(filter: $filter) { userId userName email role status createdDate lastLoginDate } }\",\"variables\":{\"filter\":{\"status\":\"ACTIVE\"}}}",
        "format": "json",
        "poll_interval": 3600,
        "result_table_name": "user_data_from_api",
        "json_field": {
            "userId": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].userId",
            "userName": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].userName",
            "email": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].email",
            "role": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].role",
            "status": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].status",
            "createdDate": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].createdDate",
            "lastLoginDate": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].lastLoginDate"
        },
        "schema": {
            "fields": {
                "userId": "string",
                "userName": "string",
                "email": "string",
                "role": "string",
                "status": "string",
                "createdDate": "string",
                "lastLoginDate": "string"
            }
        }
    }
]

combine and produce merged excel.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

multiple source is supported by Seatunnel but I am not able to find the syntax to achieve it.

What does this means? Please [edit] your question and add all details inside it

Can you please check this question and help me if you are aware with it. I have added example also.

Here it is mentioned that multiple source can be defined at the same time. but there is no sytax to achieve it.
https://seatunnel.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/concept/config/

I have solved this, Multiple source, transform it and save in multiple table parallel in Seatunnel.
{
"env": {
    "job.mode": "batch",
    "parallelism": "1"
},
"source": [
    {
        "plugin_name": "S3File",
        "bucket": "s3a://bucket-name",
        "path": "/path/to/excel/file.xlsx",
        "fs.s3a.endpoint": "s3.region.amazonaws.com",
        "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider": "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider",
        "file_format_type": "EXCEL",
        "skip_header_row_number": 1,
        "result_table_name": "user_data_from_excel",
        "sheet": 0,
        "schema": {
            "fields": {
                "user_id": "string",
                "user_name": "string",
                "email": "string",
                "role": "string",
                "status": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "plugin_name": "Http",
        "url": "http://api-endpoint.com/api/users/graphql",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "{\"query\":\"query GetAllUsers($filter: UserFilter) { getAllUsers(filter: $filter) { userId userName email role status createdDate lastLoginDate } }\",\"variables\":{\"filter\":{\"status\":\"ACTIVE\"}}}",
        "format": "json",
        "poll_interval": 3600,
        "result_table_name": "user_data_from_api",
        "json_field": {
            "userId": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].userId",
            "userName": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].userName",
            "email": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].email",
            "role": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].role",
            "status": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].status",
            "createdDate": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].createdDate",
            "lastLoginDate": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].lastLoginDate"
        },
        "schema": {
            "fields": {
                "userId": "string",
                "userName": "string",
                "email": "string",
                "role": "string",
                "status": "string",
                "createdDate": "string",
                "lastLoginDate": "string"
            }
        }
    }
],
"transform": [
    {
        "source_table_name": "user_data_from_excel",
        "result_table_name": "transform_user_data_from_excel",
        "plugin_name": "FieldMapper",
        "field_mapper": {
            "user_id": "user_id",
            "user_name": "user_name",
            "email": "email",
            "role": "role",
            "status": "status"
        }
    },
    {
        "source_table_name": "transform_user_data_from_excel",
        "result_table_name": "sink_user_data_from_excel",
        "plugin_name": "Filter",
        "fields": [
            "user_id",
            "user_name",
            "email",
            "role",
            "status"
        ]
    },
    {
        "source_table_name": "user_data_from_api",
        "result_table_name": "transform_user_data_from_api",
        "plugin_name": "FieldMapper",
        "field_mapper": {
            "userId": "userId",
            "userName": "userName",
            "email": "email",
            "role": "role",
            "status": "status",
            "createdDate": "createdDate",
            "lastLoginDate": "lastLoginDate"
        }
    },
    {
        "source_table_name": "transform_user_data_from_api",
        "result_table_name": "sql_transform_user_data_from_api",
        "plugin_name": "Sql",
        "query": "SELECT IFNULL(userId, '') AS userId, IFNULL(userName, '') AS userName, IFNULL(email, '') AS email, IFNULL(role, '') AS role, IFNULL(status, '') AS status, IFNULL(createdDate, '') AS createdDate, IFNULL(lastLoginDate, '') AS lastLoginDate FROM transform_user_data_from_api"
    },
    {
        "source_table_name": "sql_transform_user_data_from_api",
        "result_table_name": "sink_combined_user_data",
        "plugin_name": "Filter",
        "fields": [
            "userId",
            "userName",
            "email",
            "role",
            "status",
            "createdDate",
            "lastLoginDate"
        ]
    }
],
"sink": [
    {
        "source_table_name": "sink_user_data_from_excel",
        "plugin_name": "MongoDB",
        "uri": "mongodb+srv://mongodb-uri",
        "database": "database",
        "collection": "excel-collection"
    },
    {
        "source_table_name": "sink_combined_user_data",
        "plugin_name": "MongoDB",
        "uri": "mongodb+srv://mongodb-uri",
        "database": "database",
        "collection": "api-collection"
    }
]

}
